# Jenkins on Azure: Where/How to configure and install?

Tags: git, azure, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

I'm completely new to Jenkins so please apologize for my ignorance. I've been reading a lot of documentation over the internet but I'm as confused as I was when I started a couple of hours ago.

So I'm trying to build a continuous deployment pipeline. I've a web app deployed on Azure. So everytime there is a new merge with my remote master, I want it to publish to this web app automatically.

I read somewhere that I can use Jenkins to leverage this. So...
1) Where does Jenkins need to be installed? In my GIT repo? Or in the web app deployed? 
2) How do I install it? On the Jenkins page, I downloaded a .war file which I need to run using Java. I'm not running my app on a VM, it's a PaaS web app so I'm really not sure how do I deploy the Jenkins/Java files to webapp.
3) Do I need to deploy using FTP all my Jenkins files?

It would be awesome if you could point me in the right direction. Really lost here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Azure Web App allows for Git integration. You don't have to setup Jenkins for that. Take a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-continous-deployment/